# ¿Cómo puedo sumar diferencias de fechas en PHP?

Tags: php, date, datetime

¿Cómo puedo guardar en **dteDiff** la suma de las diferencias entre fechas que hago en el bucle?

```
$dteDiff = ??????;  // <-- no sé cómo definirlo aquí

for ($i=1; $i < sizeof($Result); $i+=2) { 
    $strStart = $Result[$i-1]['tiempo'];
    $strEnd = $Result[$i]['tiempo'];

    $dteStart = new DateTime($strStart); 
    $dteEnd   = new DateTime($strEnd); 

    $dteDiff  += $dteStart->diff($dteEnd); 

}

$tiempoTemporal = $dteDiff->format("%H:%I:%S"); 

echo $tiempoTemporal;
```

Comment: Diff devuelve la diferencia entre dos datetimes, asi que imagino que sera tipo datetime. Pero donde pongo ???? es porque nose como hacer un datetime vacio/nulo

Comment: por [lo que leo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11556878/1983854), sumar `diff`s no es posible, sino que probablemente debería definir un DateTime y luego hacer `->add()` de cada diff.

Comment: Y puedo definir un datetime vacío? Osea la fecha no debería sumarla, solo las horas

Comment: Lee con calma la página que enlacé en mi anterior comentario

Comment: @fedorqui Gracias con la guía que me has pasado lo he conseguido tal y como quería hacerlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo he solucionado de esta manera con la ayuda de [esta guía](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11556878/1983854) que me ha dejado en los comentarios el usuario @fedorqui

```
$dteDiff = new DateTime("0000-00-00 00:00:00");
    for ($i=1; $i < sizeof($Result); $i+=2) { 
        $strStart = $Result[$i-1]['tiempo'];
        $strEnd = $Result[$i]['tiempo'];

        $dteStart = new DateTime($strStart); 
        $dteEnd   = new DateTime($strEnd); 

        $interval = $dteStart->diff($dteEnd);

        $dteDiff->add($interval);

    }


    $tiempoTemporal =  $dteDiff->format('H:i:s');

    echo  $tiempoTemporal;
```

Lo que hace es definir un objeto `DateTime` e ir sumándole las `diff` que voy obteniendo de cada intervalo.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    $dteNow = new DateTime("now");
    $dteDiff = new DateTime("now");

    for ($i=1; $i < sizeof($Result); $i+=2) {
    $strStart = $Result[$i-1]['tiempo'];
        $strEnd = $Result[$i]['tiempo'];

        $dteStart = new DateTime($strStart); 
        $dteEnd   = new DateTime($strEnd); 

        $dteDiff->add($dteStart->diff($dteEnd));
    }

    $tiempoTemporal = $dteDiff->diff($dteNow)->format("%H:%I:%S"); 

    echo $tiempoTemporal;
    ?>
```

[diff](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.diff.php) devuelve un objeto de tipo [DateInterval](http://DateInterval). Tienes que manejarlo como tal.

Yo he declarado DateDiff como la fecha actual. En cada iteración le voy añadidendo la diferencia entre las fechas.

El resultado final es la fecha actual adelantada la suma de todos los diff. Así que si calculamos la diferencia entre esta y la fecha actual que almacenamos antes, obtenemos la diferencia de tiempo total.

Además de esto, el único cambio que he añadido ha sido cambiar el operador `+=` (que no funciona para fechas) por la función `add`.